# Create a PNG having JPG and AlphaChannel in C#

Tags: c#, png, jpeg, mask, alphablending

How can I create a PNG file if I have two separated JPG files with the image and the alpha channel?

JPG Image + JPG Mask --> PNG with transparency

I've tried WPF solutions:

```
image.OpacityMask = new ImageBrush ( new BitmapImage ( uriMask ) );
```

and System.Drawing.

```
Image bmpMask = Image.FromFile ( maskFilePath );
gfxNewImage.SetClip (  Graphics.FromImage (bmpMask) );
```

but I have problems with both (black background, or full black)

Any idea or example?

ThankYou

Comment: If it's not clear, Mask.jpg image is an image with white to black values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Let's assume that you have a JPEG Picute and a Png Picture with Alpha Channel .
You should do this than ,and it will work only if these 2 Images are the Same Size.

```
Bitmap jpegFile = new Bitmap("JpegFile.jpg");
Bitmap alphaFile = new Bitmap("Png.jpg");

for(int i=0;i<jpegFile.Width;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<jpegFile.Height;j++)
    {
       Color withAlpha = jpegFile.GetPixel(i,j);
           withAlpha.A = alphaFile.GetPixel(i,j).A;
       jpegFile.SetPixel(withAlpha);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try. In my case I have 2 JPG but I'll chose grey value as Alpha.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mario Morales this algorithm work's ,but you have to be careful when you implement it ,because if you handle with Lot of Large Images ,than you should find a way how to Multithread or if possible Optimize it .

Comment: It works with a few changes: You need a 32bpp destination image `Bitmap outImage = new Bitmap ( jpegFile.Width, jpegFile.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );` and create a color because `Color.A` is not writeable `Color withAlpha = Color.FromArgb ( alphaFile.GetPixel ( i, j ).R, jpegFile.GetPixel ( i, j ) );`

Comment: Anyway, I'll look for a most efficient algorithm, because it need some seconds to merge the images. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this parameters for Grafics object:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpMask))
{
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: It's not working `SmoothingMode`  or `InterpolationMode` doesn't seams to be related with transparency.